# pip install django on go daddy shows error

Tags: django, pip

When i run command pip install django, on go daddy it gives me the following error:

I tried to copy django packages manually into the site-packages of go daddy. I copied it from my local machine. I removed all of them.(I don't know if there is something remaining or not. But i have checked it again)  Can you please help with this?

```
 DEPRECATION: Python 2.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team, please upgrade your Python. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.6
    Collecting django
      Using cached Django-1.11.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages (from django)
    Installing collected packages: django
    Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/lmtech123/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
        status = self.run(options, args)
      File "/home/lmtech123/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
        prefix=options.prefix_path,
      File "/home/lmtech123/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
        **kwargs
      File "/home/lmtech123/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
        self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
      File "/home/lmtech123/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
        isolated=self.isolated,
      File "/home/lmtech123/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
        clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
      File "/home/lmtech123/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
        ensure_dir(destdir)
      File "/home/lmtech123/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
        os.makedirs(path)
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
        mkdir(name, mode)
    OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.11.3.dist-info'
```

Comment: You will need to update your python version. Have a look at their docs.

Comment: import django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named django

Comment: Django 1.11.x won't work with python 2.6

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid  do you have any idea to make it done? I have gone through the go daddy cpanel docs. they only provide 2.6.6

Comment: I don't use things like godaddy for hosting, sorry. Have a look at Digital Ocean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way is update to new version of Python3

`sudo apt-get install python3`

Comment: sorry bro, but i don't have root access. I hardly managed to get pip install but still it is not working that much great

Comment: Django 1.11 needs 2.7, 3.4, 3.5 or 3.6 Python version : l